# How to obtain the quasiparticle equation from Dyson equation?

Tags: many-body, greens-functions, self-energy

The problem is formulated as follows:

1. Dyson equation for zero temperature Green's function:
   \begin{equation}
   \left[
   i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t_1} - h(\vec{r}_1)
   \right]
   G(1,2)-\int d3 \Sigma(1,3)G(3,2)=\delta(1,2)
   \tag{1}
   \end{equation}
   in which
   \begin{equation*}
   h(\vec{r}_1)\equiv-\dfrac{\nabla^2}{2}+V_H(\vec{r}_1)+V_{ext}(\vec{r}_1)
   \qquad
   1\equiv(\vec{r}_1,t_1)
   \end{equation*}
2. Take Fourier transformation to the energy domain:
   \begin{align}
   \left[
   -\omega - h(\vec{r}_1)
   \right]
   G(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2;\omega)-\int d\vec{r}_3
   \Sigma(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_3;\omega)
   G(\vec{r}_3,\vec{r}_2;\omega)
   =
   \delta (\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2) \tag{2}
   \end{align}
3. The zero temperature Green's function under quasiparticle approximation can be represented as:
   \begin{equation}
   G(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2;\omega)
   =
   \sum_i
   \dfrac{\psi_i^{QP}(\vec{r}_1)\psi_i^{QP*}(\vec{r}_2)}{\omega-E_i^{QP}}
   \tag{3}
   \end{equation}
   Insert $(3)$ into (2) one can obtain the following quasiparticle equation:
   \begin{equation}
   \left[
   -\dfrac{1}{2}\nabla^2+V_H(\vec{r})+V_{ext}(\vec{r})
   \right]
   \psi_i^{QP}(\vec{r})
   +
   \int \Sigma(\vec{r},\vec{r}';E_i^{QP})\psi_i^{QP}(\vec{r}')d\vec{r}'
   =E_i^{QP}
   \psi_i^{QP}(\vec{r})
   \tag{4}
   \end{equation}

How can I complete the final step? I cannot build any connection between $(2)$ and $(3)$.

[This problem is related to $(6)$, $(7)$ and $(8)$.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/wcms.1265)

For completeness, the Fourier transform of $(1)$ is presented:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This [paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.145.561) by Sham and Kohn and this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.129.897) by Layzer citing Morse and Fesbach argue that $G(\vec{r},\vec{r'};E)$ admits diagonal like expansion in terms of bi-orthogonal basis of integro-differential operator appearing in Eq.(4) above.

Comment: @Sunyam Have you go through the details? (By the way, thanks for your nice help so many times)

Comment: The papers cited above are bit sketchy and hand-way, have to check more details like when does the integro-differential operator $\int d\vec{r}_3\left[-\omega - h(\vec{r}_1)\right]\delta(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_3)-\Sigma(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_3;\omega)$ admit bi-orthonormal eigenbasis.

Comment: You might find Sec. 3.6 (pg. no. 153) of Datta's [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/electronic-transport-in-mesoscopic-systems/1E55DEF5978AA7B843FF70337C220D8B) and [this](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/1987/T19A/039/meta) paper by  W van Haeringen, B Farid and D Lenstra  a useful read. Also see my comment on hft's answer.

Comment: @Sunyam: Could you provide an answer based on what you have read?

Comment: Will try to write an answer soon.

Comment: @Sunyam Hi, I have been waiting for your answer.

Comment: I have been busy writing my thesis. Will do it once i get a stretch of time. Although I don't have complete answer in the sense that when does an integral operator admit a complete bi-othonormal eigen basis. If this is assumed the proof is similar to that provided in the references i have cited above. When you choose approximately a finite single particle (orbital) basis and represent you field operators in that basis, the answer boils down to that of finite matrices.

Comment: If these matrices have non-degenerate eigenvalues (left and right), then the greens function can be written as a pseudo diagonal representation. When the quasipaticle dyson operator in matrix version has degeneracies where algebraic and geometric multiplicities of degenerate eigenvalues are different, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I complete the final step? I cannot build any connection between (2) and (3).

You need to use the completeness of the eigenfunctions

$$
\sum_i \psi_i(\vec r_1)\psi_i^*(\vec r_2) = \delta(\vec r_1 - \vec r_2)
$$

After plugging in the above completeness relationship on the RHS and your definition of the Green's function on the LHS, the resulting equation is:

$$
\sum_i \psi_i^*(\vec r_2)\frac{1}{(\omega - E_i)}\left \{(\omega - h(\vec r_1))\psi_i(\vec r_1) - \int d^3r_3 \Sigma(\vec r_1,\vec r_3)\psi_i(\vec r_3)\right\}
=\sum_i \psi_i(\vec r_1)\psi_i^*(\vec r_2)
$$

Note, In the above equation I have corrected an error in the Fourier transform of the LHS in your original statement of the problem. Your $(-\omega -h(\vec r))$ has been changed to $(\omega - h(\vec r))$. This is because the $i\partial/\partial t$ transforms to $\omega$ not $-\omega$.

The coefficients of $\psi_i^*(\vec r_2)$ have to be equal by completeness so:
$$
\frac{1}{(\omega - E_i)}\left \{(\omega - h(\vec r_1))\psi_i(\vec r_1) - \int d^3r_3 \Sigma(\vec r_1,\vec r_3)\psi_i(\vec r_3)\right\}
=\psi_i(\vec r_1)
$$
Or
$$
(\omega - h(\vec r_1))\psi_i(\vec r_1) - \int d^3r_3 \Sigma(\vec r_1,\vec r_3)\psi_i(\vec r_3)
=\psi_i(\vec r_1)(\omega - E_i)
$$

Cancel the $\omega \psi_i(\vec r_1)$ from both sides and then multiply both sides by $-1$ to get:
$$
h(\vec r_1)\psi_i(\vec r_1) + \int d^3r_3 \Sigma(\vec r_1,\vec r_3)\psi_i(\vec r_3)
=\psi_i(\vec r_1)E_i
$$

Comment: Seems there is a problem related to the definition of Fourier transform to cancel $\omega \psi_i(\vec{r}_1)$, I will fix it. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, that it right. Your LHS fourier transform should have (w - h(r)) not (-w - h(r)). I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @hft You seem to have assumed that the integral operator (which parametricaly depends on $\omega$) $\int d\vec{r}'\left[\left(\omega - h(\vec{r})\right)\delta(\vec{r},\vec{r}')-\Sigma(\vec{r},\vec{r}')\right]\boldsymbol{\cdot}$ has an orthonormal basis which is not always guaranteed (as this operator is not Hermitian or Normal in general), however it might admit bi-orthonormal basis (not sure if this is guaranteed always). So the above arguments need to be generalized taking account of this.